# Can we apply Calculation formulas in the values directly in the MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angularjs, database, formula

**I want to apply some customised mathematics formula on values present in the database *!..Directly In The Database..!* but I don't know how to do it.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can express your formulas using [MySql built in math functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html) you can put them in SELECT statements.

```
SELECT x, y, SQRT(x*x, y*y) dist FROM mytable
```

is a simple example.

You can declare a *[generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)* in a table.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
 ADD COLUMN dist DOUBLE AS SQRT( x*x + y*y);
```

Then `SELECT x, y, dist FROM mytable` gives you the computed result.

You can create views of tables using SELECT statements with formulas in them.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myComputedView AS
SELECT x, y, SQRT(x*x, y*y) dist FROM mytable
```

Then `SELECT x, y, dist FROM myComputedView` gives your result.

You didn't tell us much about your problem, so it's hard to recommend one of these techniques over the others.

Beware: in scaled-up applications, the database server is a scarce resource. It's often best to put complex calculations elsewhere in your system, in client or web server code.

Comment: As you suggested that complex calculations are best in the system, so I put my code in the web server code so that the calculations are done before they are saved in the database. I applied the formulas on the field just before applying the SQL commands for their insertion. Thanks for your support. It helped a lot